# Inconsistent spacing after theorem environment (KOMA)

Tags: spacing, koma-script, theorems, mdframed, thmtools

After including the `parskip=half-` option I'm getting inconsistent spacing after theorem environments (Sometimes there's more space than it should). If I don't use that option the problem goes away but I need that option.

I've tried some sugestions written on this site but there's no noticeable effect on the document. I include a MWE with the suggestions commented out because maybe I didn't tried them correctly.

Ideally between each block of text there should be the same vertical space as two consecutive paragraphs. If there's more space around theorem environments it should be the same.

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{mdgreenbox}{%
% suppressfirstparskip,
linewidth=2pt,rightline=false,leftline=true,
topline=false,bottomline=false,linecolor=green,
backgroundcolor=green!5,
% skipabove=2\parskip,
% skipbelow=0,
}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{green!70!black},
mdframed={style=mdgreenbox},
% spacebelow=0,
]{greenbox}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdbluebox}{%
% suppressfirstparskip,
roundcorner = 10pt,linewidth=1pt,innerbottommargin=9pt,
linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!5,
% skipabove=2\parskip,
% skipbelow=0,
}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{blue},
mdframed={style=mdbluebox},headpunct={\\[3pt]},
postheadspace={0pt},
% spacebelow=0,
]{bluebox}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=bluebox,name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=greenbox,name=Observation,sibling=theorem]{observation}

% \begingroup
%     \makeatletter
%     \@for\theoremstyle:=definition,remark,plain\do{%
%         \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname th@\theoremstyle\endcsname{%
%             \setlength\thm@preskip{0pt}
%             \setlength\thm@postskip{0pt}
%             }%
%         }
% \endgroup

% \makeatletter
% \def\thm@space@setup{\thm@preskip=0pt
% \thm@postskip=0pt}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
% \KOMAoptions{parskip=false}
\begin{observation}
    \lipsum[47]
\end{observation}

% \KOMAoptions{parskip=half-}
\lipsum[47]

\lipsum[47]

\begin{observation}
    \lipsum[47]
\end{observation}

\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[47]
\end{theorem}

\begin{observation}
    \lipsum[47]
\end{observation}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** If I use the options `skipabove=0,skipbelow=0` inside `\mdfdefinestyle` and the options `spaceabove=0,spacebelow=0` inside `\declaretheoremstyle`, every vertical space between blocks of text (paragraphs) gets reduced to zero or almost zero. except the first one.

My hypothesis is that the theorem environment or maybe mdframed puts a parskip after the block of text but the next paragraph doesn't detect it and puts another parskip. How do I tell the document that I don't want another parskip?
[image: Spaces=0]

Comment: If I don't use the `parskip=half-` option, it still looks bad (but not as bad I think).

Comment: Try `\mdfsetup{skipbelow=-3pt}`. Though this is not a perfect solution.